# Как изменять элементы Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть ListBox такого типа:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         x:Name="NoteList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFD7B4F3" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" Margin="2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Внутри cs кода этого окна я хочу изменять TextBlock.Text каждого элемента ListBox. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: меняйте свойство Title у соответствующего Node и WPF сам его обновит

Comment: @Exploding Kitten дело в том, что сделать это мне нужно именно через код окна, а не через ViewModel в котором хранится Note

Comment: Зачем вам это понадобилось? Возможно вы ищете неправильное решение для своей задачи

Comment: @Андрей NOP вообще, я хочу сделать так, чтобы TextBlock.Text "обрезался" ("Тек...")  в зависимости от ширины ListBox

Comment: Ага, значит вам нужен конвертер, скорее даже мультиконвертер

Comment: @Андрей NOP спасибо. Не знал что такая штука существует

Comment: Есть более полезная штука, называется: [TextTrimming](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_TextBlock_TextTrimming). Как раз у данного контрола есть такое свойство и контрол сам обрежет при надобности текст.

Comment: @John я задал TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" и по какой-то причине ничего не изменилось. Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: А горизонтальная полоса прокрутки появилась?

Comment: @АндрейNOP она у меня и без TextTrimming была

Comment: Ну поэтому и не обрезает, что ListBox выдает столько ширины, сколько контрол у него просит

Comment: @АндрейNOP я поставил ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" к ListBox. Горизонтальная прокрутка пропала, но TextTrimming по прежнему никакого эффекта не дает. Наверное все таки буду реализовывать с помощью мультиконвертера

Comment: Это потому что у вас там еще и StackPanel, он тоже дает контролу столько ширины, сколько у него просят. Без StackPanel работает нормально

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо. Подкорректировал код, теперь все работает